# Filter list on the fly by a parameter

Tags: reactjs, filter

I want to order a list using a parameter given by URL.
I pass the parameter using React-router, with this parameter I do this:

```
const newlist = arrayList.filter(el => el.id === urlId);
console.log(newlist);
```

But unfortunately `newlist` isn't rendered and it is empty. The `urlId` is received, but the filter seems doesn't have the time to filter and print correctly.

Any hint?

Comment: Need more info, but one guess I have is that your `urlId` is a string, and your `id` is a number. Just a guess because that's one way `el.id === urlId` could fail even when it's populated.

Comment: And you were right. If you write this as Answer I will accept it. Thank you mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `el.id` is a number and `urlId` is a string because it's coming from a route. So it seems like you just need to convert `urlId` to a number.

Comment: Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Mark np glad I could help!